# Should uno be said if the next card is played from draw pile

Tags: uno

If you played your second to last card and said Uno as required. If on the next turn you are unable to play, but you play the card immediately from the draw pile. Are you required to say uno again?

Comment: nb: you don't play "from the draw pile". You play from your hand. If it's your turn and you cannot (or don't want to play), then you must draw (draw a card from the draw pile and put it in your hand). You then have the option to play a card (from your hand) if you now can (or now want to).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the draw takes you back up to two cards in your and and the play takes you back down to one card which requires you to declare uno. You might make a house rule that would change that but outside of that you would still be required to call uno and get a penalty if you don't and get caught.

Comment: There's a rule that states if you have a playable card and choose not to play it and instead go to the draw pile. Once you draw a card you can't play from you hand anymore. That suggested to me that the cards already in your hand is viewed differently as the one from the draw pile until your turn is over. If that's the case, wouldn't immediately discarding the card from the draw pile mean I remain with 1 card?

Comment: That rule has nothing to do with the fact that drawing a card takes you from 1 card in your hand to 2 cards in your hand. Whenever you go from 2 cards to 1 card you are required to call uno and it doesn't matter if you started the turn with 1 card.